# Displaying value on text filed onChange of react-select

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-select

I am using react-select(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) for the field 'Return Templates'.

When value of Return Templates change, corresponding Note should be shown in the 'Notes' filed, which is a text field.

```
<li>
                        <Field
                            name="ReturnTemplates"
                            type="text"
                            label="Return Templates"
                            title="Return Templates"
                        >

                        </Field>

                        <Select 
                                        options={paymentTemplates && paymentTemplates.map(value => (
                                            {
                                                value: value.NotesTemplateId,
                                                label: value.TemplateLabel
                                            }
                                        ))

                                        } 
                                        onChange={(e)=>{ change('ReturnTemplates', e.value); this.onchange({target:e})  }}
                                    /> 

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Field
                            name="Notes"
                            component={this.renderPaymentField}
                            type="text"
                            onChange={this.notechange}
                            label="Notes"
                            Required={true}
                            title="Notes Required"
                        />
                    </li>
                    <li>
```

The onchange() and renderPaymentField() are as follows

```
onchange(e)
    {
        const {
        paymentTemplates,
            InsertPaymentReturn
        } = this.props;

        var id=e.target.value;
        var template=_.find(paymentTemplates,{NotesTemplateId:Number(id)});
        InsertPaymentReturn.values.Notes=template.TemplateText;
        this.setState({Notes:template.TemplateText})
    }

renderPaymentField = ({ input, label, Required, type, title, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
        <div title={title}>
            <div className={touched && error ? 'add-list_key alert' : 'add-list_key'}>{label}
                {Required && <span className="add-list_required"> *</span>}
            </div>
            <div className="add-list_value" style={{ 'minWidth': 230, 'maxWidth': 230 }}>
                <input {...input} type={type} />
                {touched && error && <span>*</span>}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

There was no problem in displaying Notes when I used normal dropdown using `<select>` and `<option>` tags for Return Templates.

[image]

When I used `react-select` , during onchange Notes is not displaying , but when debugged the 'value' of Notes is there.

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: We would need to know how the `Field` component is implemented as well as what `renderPaymentField` does

Comment: I still fail to understand your code, since they are in pieces. Do you think you can setup a working example in a website like codesandbox.com?